# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'This function cannot be performed because the message has changed

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, email-attachments

I've been trying to build a VSTO Outlook Addin.

The Addin dose the following:

1- saves the email attachments to a certain path

2- writes the path of the saved attachments in the Email body

3- delete the attachments from the email

4- saves the email

My problem is whenever I try to save an email after editing it with the links, I get the following error:

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException**: 'This function cannot be performed because the message has changed.

the error occurs only when trying to save the email using: **getItem.Save();**

I am not holding any references to the mailitem, and also releasing all the object using Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);

the save function only occurs one time in the whole code.

Note: the exception isn't always thrown, sometimes the save works and sometimes not

How do I solve this problem ?

the code:

```
class SaveInvoice {

    dynamic activeWindow = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow();

    private MailItem getCurrentEmailObject() {
       
        try {
            if (activeWindow is Explorer) {
                dynamic i = activeWindow.currentFolder;
                if (activeWindow.Selection.Count > 0) {
                    object selObject = activeWindow.Selection[1];
                    if (selObject is MailItem) {
                        MailItem mailItem = (selObject as MailItem);
                        return mailItem;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                return activeWindow.currentitem;
            }
        } catch (System.Exception) {
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
    private void addLinkToEmail(string savedpath) {

        if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow() is Explorer) {
            MailItem selObject = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
            selObject.HTMLBody = savedpath + "<br>" + Environment.NewLine + selObject.HTMLBody;
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(selObject);
            
        }
        else {
            MailItem selObject = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
            selObject.HTMLBody = savedpath + "<br>" + Environment.NewLine + selObject.HTMLBody;
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(selObject);
        }
    }
    private void saveEmail(string guid, string folderStoreID) {

        Application outlookApplication = new Application();
        NameSpace outlookNamespace = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");      
        MailItem getItem = (MailItem)outlookNamespace.GetItemFromID(guid, folderStoreID);

        getItem.Save();   //the Expection is Thrown here
      
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(getItem);
    }

    private string SaveFileTo(string initStorage, string fileName) {
        SaveFileDialog fd = new SaveFileDialog();
        fd.AddExtension = true;
        fd.ValidateNames = true;
        fd.FileName = fileName;
        fd.InitialDirectory = initStorage;
        fd.Filter = "PDF files|*.pdf";
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            return fd.FileName;
        return "";
    }

    public void saveInvoice() {

        MailItem mailObject = getCurrentEmailObject();
        if (mailObject != null) {

            string CustomerName = "CutomerNameTest"
        
                foreach (Attachment attachment in mailObject.Attachments) {

                    string saveToPath = "stringPath";           

                    if (attachment.FileName.Contains(".pdf")) {

                        attachment.SaveAsFile(saveToPath);
                        attachment.Delete();
                        addLinkToEmail(saveToPath);
                    }
                }
                string guid = mailObject.EntryID;
                var folderStoreID = mailObject.Parent.StoreID;
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailObject);

                try {
                    saveEmail(guid, folderStoreID);
                } catch (COMException e) {

                   MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                }
                activeWindow = null;
        }
    }
    private string getSenderEmailAddress(MailItem mail) {
        AddressEntry sender = mail.Sender;
        string SenderEmailAddress = "";

        if (sender.AddressEntryUserType == OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry
            || sender.AddressEntryUserType == OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry) {
            ExchangeUser exchUser = sender.GetExchangeUser();
            if (exchUser != null) {
                SenderEmailAddress = exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
            }
        }
        else {
            SenderEmailAddress = mail.SenderEmailAddress;
        }
        return SenderEmailAddress;
    }
}
```

the invoice class is being called at the button click in the ribbon:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveInvoice currentData = new SaveInvoice();
        currentData.saveInvoice();
        //MessageBox.Show(currentData.getCurrentEmailData());
    }
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1:**

i changed the code to:

```
class SaveInvoice {

    dynamic activeWindow = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow();

    private MailItem getCurrentEmailObject() {
       
        try {
            if (activeWindow is Explorer) {
                dynamic i = activeWindow.currentFolder;
                if (activeWindow.Selection.Count > 0) {
                    object selObject = activeWindow.Selection[1];
                    if (selObject is MailItem) {
                        MailItem mailItem = (selObject as MailItem);
                        return mailItem;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                return activeWindow.currentitem;
            }
        } catch (System.Exception) {
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
    private void addLinkToEmail(string savedpath, MailItem mailItem) {
        mailItem.HTMLBody = savedpath + "<br>" + Environment.NewLine + mailItem.HTMLBody;
    }
  
    public void saveInvoice() {

        MailItem mailObject = getCurrentEmailObject();
        if (mailObject != null) {

                foreach (Attachment attachment in mailObject.Attachments) {

                    string saveToPath = "savePath";
                    attachment.SaveAsFile(saveToPath);
                    attachment.Delete();
                    addLinkToEmail(saveToPath, mailObject);
                    
                }
                mailObject.Save();
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailObject);
                activeWindow = null;
        }
    }
    private string getSenderEmailAddress(MailItem mail) {
        AddressEntry sender = mail.Sender;
        string SenderEmailAddress = "";

        if (sender.AddressEntryUserType == OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry
            || sender.AddressEntryUserType == OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry) {
            ExchangeUser exchUser = sender.GetExchangeUser();
            if (exchUser != null) {
                SenderEmailAddress = exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
            }
        }
        else {
            SenderEmailAddress = mail.SenderEmailAddress;
        }
        return SenderEmailAddress;
    }
}
```

still getting the error sometimes, i am trying to use the same mailobject throughout the whole code, but the problem is occuring

EDIT 3:

i deleted all the other functions and left only one to save:

```
public void saveInvoice(){
MailItem mailObject = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow().Selection[1];
try {
    if (mailObject != null) {

        foreach (Attachment attachment in mailObject.Attachments) {
            string saveToPath = "saveToPath";
            attachment.SaveAsFile(saveToPath);
            attachment.Delete();
            mailObject.Save();
        }
    }

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailObject);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow().Selection[1]);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow());
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application);
}

catch (System.Exception){
    throw;
}
```

}

its called dirctly after the click event from Ribbon1.cs

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
       saveInvoice();
    }
```

the System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException is still sometimes occurring when trying to save the mailitem (mailObject.Save()), I released ALL the underlying COM objects that i know off

Answer (score 1):

In VSTO add-ins you should use a safe `Application` instance provided by the `ThisAddin` class instead of creating a new instance in the code.

```
 private void saveEmail(string guid, string folderStoreID) {

        Application outlookApplication = new Application();
```

The [Program VSTO Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/programming-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2022) states the following:

> You can start writing your VSTO Add-in code in the ThisAddIn class. Visual Studio automatically generates this class in the ThisAddIn.vb (in Visual Basic) or ThisAddIn.cs (in C#) code file in your VSTO Add-in project. The Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime automatically instantiates this class for you when the Microsoft Office application loads your VSTO Add-in.

> To access the object model of the host application, use the `Application` field of the `ThisAddIn` class. This field returns an object that represents the current instance of the host application.

Your code may look like that instead:

```
 private void saveEmail(string guid, string folderStoreID) {

     Application outlookApplication = Globals.ThisAddin.Application;
```

You need to review the code base and refactor functions to re-use the retrieved Outlook item instead of getting it in each function separately. For example, almost in all functions I see the following:

```
 if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow() is Explorer) {
            MailItem selObject = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
```

But at the same time there is a function which returns the currently shown item:

```
private MailItem getCurrentEmailObject() {
       
        try {
            if (activeWindow is Explorer) {
                dynamic i = activeWindow.currentFolder;
                if (activeWindow.Selection.Count > 0) {
                    object selObject = activeWindow.Selection[1];
                    if (selObject is MailItem) {
                        MailItem mailItem = (selObject as MailItem);
                        return mailItem;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                return activeWindow.currentitem;
            }
        } catch (System.Exception) {
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

So, you need to extract it once and re-use through the code until you are done with all you modifications/work.

Also I'd recommend releasing underlying COM objects instantly. For example:

```
MailItem selObject = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
```

A single line of code contains multiple property and method calls that return COM objects. There objects are left in memory when you are done. The `ActiveExplorer` method returns an instance of the `Explorer` class. Then you call the Selection property which returns the `Selection` object which also was left in memory.

Also I noticed that you use the `foreach` loop in the code:

```
foreach (Attachment attachment in mailObject.Attachments) {
```

Note, in this case the attachment object is not release with each iteration. I'd suggest using the `for` instead where you could retrieve the attachment object explicitly and then release it with each iteration.

Note, there is no need to call the `Save` method each time an attachment is removed. So, place the following call outside of the loop:

```
mailObject.Save();
```

Finally, the `HTMLBody` property returns a string which represents the message body in the HTML format. So, when you set any value to the property you need to be sure that you set a valid HTML string, for example:

```
private void addLinkToEmail(string savedpath, MailItem mailItem) {
        mailItem.HTMLBody = savedpath + "<br>" + Environment.NewLine + mailItem.HTMLBody;
    }
```

The code inserts a path string before the HTML string, that means before the `<html>` or `<body>` tags. Instead, you need to find the opening `<body>` tag and insert your string there to preserve any formatting.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, i followed your instructors and posted my answer under Edit1 in the question

Comment: You need to review your code once again to release ALL underlying COM objects and create a well-formed HTML string to modify the `HTMLBody` property.

Comment: i wrote the changes in the original post under Edit3, tried everything i am still getting the error,  i'll leave the HTMLBody for now, i just want to able to save the email after deleting the Attachment

Comment: `foreach (Attachment attachment in mailObject.Attachments)`

Comment: You need to move the `mailObject.Save();` outside of the loop. There is no need to call the `Save` method each time an attachment is removed from the mail item.

Comment: `foreach (Attachment attachment in mailObject.Attachments)` i released it with `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailObject.Attachments)`, as for `mailObject.Save()` i took it out from the foreach loop, iam currently testing the code, i will post back the result as soon as i am finished, thank you

Comment: In case of `foreach` loop you don't release the `Attachments` collection.